# Trigger onTap on underlying PhotoView from overlapping panResponder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a scene which uses both a panResonder with an `<Animated.View>` and a `<PhotoView>` from the react-native-photoView Api. The panResponder handles animation for a circle within the `<Animated.View>`, while the `<PhotoView>` handles the zooming on tap and pinch-to-zoom of a background image. The circle (the marker im using) of the `<Animated.View>` is rendered on top of the image, but it is not contained within it (it is not nested within), as this is not possible within the Api, so they are siblings with a common `<View>` parent.

What I am trying to achieve: I want to be able to get the coordinates of the marker in relation to the background image, if the background image is zoomed in, i want the markers coordinates to be updated accordingly. So if i press the marker when its over the head of a person of the image, I expect the coordinates of the head on the image.

The `<PhotoView>` API gives the callback function onTap, which I can easily grab the correct scaled x and y values of from the image. The `<Animated.View>`, the marker, i can easily get the coordinates according to the parents view, given by the panResponder. So i imagined that if i could register the tap of the marker for the onTap function of the `<PhotoView>`, that would trigger the callback function and i would get the event containing the scaled (x,y) pair for that location.

The problem: Since the marker is overlapping the `<PhotoView>`, and since they are not nested, the onTap for the marker does not trigger the onTap for the `<PhotoView>`, which might be expected.

Here is the mentioned code from my render method

```
    return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <PhotoView
         onViewTap={(data) => }
         onLoadEnd={(e) => }
         onLoadStart={(event) =>}
         source={{ uri:  }}
         onLoad={(event) =>}
         onTap={(event) => console.log(`onTap called: 
         ${event.nativeEvent.x} ${event.nativeEvent.y}`)}
         onScale={() => }
         minimumZoomScale={1}
         maximumZoomScale={3}
         scale={this.state.scale}
         resizeMode={'contain'}
         androidScaleType={'fitXY'}
        />
    <View
        pointerEvents={this.pointer}
        style={styles.draggableContainer}>
        <Animated.View
            {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
            style={[this.state.xy, styles.circle]}>
        </Animated.View>
    </View>
    </View>
</View>

)
```

How could I solve this problem? Perhaps I cant trigger the onTap, how could I solve it then?

**Edit**: I've tried creating a second panResponder( Parent of `<PhotoView>`) for tracking the events of the image, e.g zooming and then draggin the image. If I could then update the offset of each touch, I believe I could then obtain the 'corrected' pixels if the current zoom scale and offset is given when the marker is touched. Right now I am playing around with this approach, but its not going too great.

`setScale()` will handle everything of the background image triggering zoom. So here I add the listener only when the zoom has occured, and set the state scale of the zoom given from the event argument passed.

```
setScale(e) {
    // Add listener to the panValue of the panResponder
    this.panListener2 = this.state.pan2.addListener((value) => this.currentPanValue2 = value);
    // Set the panResponders values to 0,0 when new touch event is registered
    this.state.pan2.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });

    // Set updated scale value of the image
    this.setState({ scaleF: e.scale });
}
```

Then, my idea is to logg the sought values of the panResponder2, this is where the magic should happen, but its quite dry on spellpower at this moment.

```
this.panResponderImage = PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, {
        dx: this.state.pan2.x,
        dy: this.state.pan2.y
    }]),
    onPanResponderRelease: (e) => {
        this.state.pan2.setOffset({
            x: this.currentPanValue2.x, y: this.currentPanValue2.y
        });
        console.log((e.nativeEvent.pageX - (this.currentPanValue2.x)),
             (e.nativeEvent.pageY - this.currentPanValue2.y));

        this.state.pan2.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    }
});
```

So with this new approach im basically trying to do what is already being done by the onTap call, which feels like a waste of everyones time, however, if I could get it to work I could overlook this slight annoyance.

Can you see where i need to add x or y? Have you done anything like this before and perhaps know how I should approach it? What are the necessary steps I have to take in the panResponderRelease() to get the best values?

Thanks for reading and have a good day!